# Pole Of a matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

In Quantum mechanics, Resonance is defined as pole of Scattering Matrix. I tried searching on the internet about pole of a matrix but I didnt find much. Wikipedia says A zero of a meromorphic function $f$ is a complex number $z$ such that $f(z) = 0$. A pole of $f$ is a zero of $\frac{1}{f}$ .
I dont understand how pole of a function and a matrix is related

Answer (score 0):

You are right that a matrix does not have a pole. But the matrices in scattering theory may be matrices whose entries are functions, not numbers. Those functions can have poles.